# how to run topic model on 20000 documents at once?

Tags: bash, topic-modeling, mallet

I have 20000 news documents to run topic modeling on it:

I want to see the topic dynamics and evolution from the documents. I tried to use the following batch script with Topic modeling by mallet but not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /Users/JasonDou/code/internet_finance/bydocafterseg2; do
    ./bin/mallet import-dir --input /Users/JasonDou/code/internet_finance/bydocafterseg2/159047443.txt  --output bydoc-input.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an asterisk:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "/Users/JasonDou/code/internet_finance/bydocafterseg2/"*; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    ./bin/mallet import-dir --input "$filename" \
      --output bydoc-input.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
done
```

The above will list iterate over each file in `bydocafterseg2`. You can change it to all `.txt` files with: `"bydocafterseg2/"*".txt"`

Comment: it helps! I have a follow up question: how can I name the output file according the filename above? like "$filename"-input.mallet ?

Comment: `--output "$filename-input.mallet"`?